# Reflux/React - Managing state with asynchronous data

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I think this is a trivial use case but I am still getting to grips with aspects of Flux and React. In my example I am using Reflux and React Router.

I have a basic component that displays the details of a sales lead. Using the lead id from the URL parameter, it makes a call to my service to get the lead:

```
var React = require('react'),
    Reflux = require('reflux');

var leadStore = require('../stores/lead'),
    actions = require('../actions');

var Lead = React.createClass({
  render : function () {
    var p = this.props.lead;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{p.details}</h2>
        <p>{p.description}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(leadStore)],

  componentDidMount : function () {
    actions.loadLead(this.props.routeParams.id);
  },

  render : function () {
    if (!this.state.lead) {
      return (
        <Lead lead={this.state.lead} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>Loading</div>
    );
  }
});
```

If I don't include the conditional check then on the first pass the render method will fire and kick off an error because there's nothing in state. I could set some default state parameters but what I would ultimately like to do is show a pre-loader.

The approach I've taken feels wrong and I was wondering what the common practice was for this situation? All the examples I've seen use default states or pre-load mixins. I'm interested in knowing if there's a better way to make use of the component life-cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from if (!this.state.lead) should be if (this.state.lead) it looks ok. Another way would be.

```js
module.exports = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(leadStore)],

  componentDidMount : function () {
    actions.loadLead(this.props.routeParams.id);
  },

  render : function () {
    var returnIt;
    if (this.state.lead) {
      returnIt = (<Lead lead={this.state.lead} />);
    } else {
      returnIt = (<div>Loading</div>);
    }
    return (returnIt);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

React [Wait to Render](http://bvaughn.github.io/react-wait-to-render/) is worth checking out. It's a tiny component that will display a loader until all of the component's props are defined, e.g. while we wait for `lead` data. Good for keeping the `render` clean, as easy as:

```
<WaitToRender
  wrappedComponent={Lead}
  loadingIndicator={LoadingComponent}
  lead={this.state.lead} />
```

You can also use it to [decorate](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators) your `Lead` component.